# Get Text from a Div with specific ID's using DOM (getElementById help)

Tags: php, html, dom

I have the following code snippet I'm trying to get the text from:

```
<span class="article-title1"><div id="user-sub-summary">Love to get text</div></span>
<div id="user-sub-intro"><p>this is my intro paragraph</p></div>
```

I'm trying to get just the text in the  with the id "user-sub-summary"
Ultimately I'm going to get this text and display it in an editable textbox so people can change this if they would like.

my existing code looks like this ($intro = the html snippet above):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($intro);
var_dump($dom->getElementById('user-sub-summary'));
```

This just returns 'NULL' on the page - but I can't figure out why.  I've tried searching here, I've googled, I've looked everywhere to try and figure this out but have come up empty handed.

Comment: Look.For stuff that can be done on the client side,do it on the client side.Do not overload your server with stuff that can be done with js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a doctype. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php#100402

And it's always a good practice to validate your data before parsing.

$dom->validateOnParse = true;

Comment: Is there an easy way to add the DTD to my snippet?  Or would I have to add it manually like: $intro = <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>$intro</body></html>

??

Comment: I got it all working, but I'm going to go forward with a Javascript solution I think.

Comment: Sorry, I was out - ideally, your HTML will be a separate file. If you must do it all within 1 code-set, I recommend using JavaScript - JQuery is my framework of choice.
 `code`
function getText(originID, destination){
var textString = $(originID).html(); 
$(destination).html = textString;
} `code`

Comment: Just call that function with all the parameters and bind it to an event and you're set

Answer (score 0):

first : I suggest using a javascript framework (JQuery)

second : be sure that your DOM is finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("#user-sub-summary").html());
});
```

Hope it help

Comment: Got it working - I think I will do as Aleksandar and you recommended and move forward trying to use Javascript.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: what was finally the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dynamic HTML or jQuery, make sure the dynamic object is appended to the document model before trying to 'get' or select it. That is, Javascript's getElementById method searches DOM objects attached to the document root (directly or through other objects attached to one another).

In Javascript, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for an example appending dynamic content. Insert `alert(currentDiv.innerHTML);` after line 11 to see the desired text.

In jQuery, use (where "parentId" is the Id of an object attached to the DOM document root):

```
var childObject = $('<div id="childId">Text</div>');
$("#parentId").append(childObject);
alert( $("#childId").text() );
```

or

```
alert( childObject.text() );
```

And for the comment by user744186, I assume this is running on the client.